# Cloudflare > Nginx reverse proxy (NPM) > Digital Ocean specific problem

Tags: dns, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having this very specific problem. Will try my best to describe what is the deal.

I am running a server on Digital Ocean behind NGINX Reverse Proxy (configurations are done through NGINX Proxy Manager).
I create A record in my cloudflare (mydomain.com) pointing to digital ocean droplets IP.
Everything works good:

REQUEST FROM INTERNET > CLOUDFLARE PROXY > NGINX REVERSE PROXY > DIGITAL OCEAN SERVER.

**However**, When I am trying to put a single IP address (for example address of my VPN server X.X.X.X ) in nginx reverse proxies Access List (So that only that IP will have access to the server).
Everything stops working, and I know why.
Nginx  waits for requests only from X.X.X.X , and because the scheme appears to be like this:

X.X.X.X  > CLOUDFLARE PROXY > NGINX REVERSE PROXY > DIGITAL OCEAN SERVER

I is logical that NGINX doesn't send any response (because it is waiting for connection from X.X.X.X and the connection comes from CLOUDFLARES PROXYS IP)

**The issue is**, that when I am turning off cloudflare proxy (toggling the little orange cloud to OFF position) Server doesn't respond. With my understanding, when I turn it off, connection should be coming like this:

X.X.X.X   > NGINX REVERSE PROXY > DIGITAL OCEAN SERVER

Anyone knows what the issue might be? (I am guessing there might be another cloudflare server between My VPN and NGINX Proxy? Or I don't know something of that kind)
Let me know if you need any additional info I will try to provide everything possible. Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved thanks to @Paolo s answer. I decided to start from the easiest of the cases he provided, so I added all cloudflare IP ranges to my NGINX Revers Proxies access list. Because I run docker behind that proxy, I have several containers that need to be public and some that need to be private (accessible only with my x.x.x.x VPN)

Case #1 (with orange cloud ON) Now I am able to access conainers that I wanted to be public from any IP address (thanks to new Access List mentioned above)

REQUEST FROM INTERNET > CLOUDFLARE PROXY > NGINX REVERSE PROXY > DIGITAL OCEAN SERVER > **DOCKER PUBLC CONTAINER**

Case #2 (with gray cloud OFF) after @Paolo pointed out that there may be a connectivity issue between X.X.X.X and NGINX I started to check all configs. He was right, the reverse proxy was misconfigured. After fixing the issue everything started to work as I planned. (Access list was switched from previous one to only allowing X.X.X.X in this case)

X.X.X.X > NGINX REVERSE PROXY > DIGITAL OCEAN SERVER > **DOCKER PRIVATE CONTAINER**

Thanks everyone and special thanks to @Paolo

Answer (score 2):

For the 1st scenario (orange cloud), you can configure your NGINX to restore the visitor's original IP (`X.X.X.X`), since Cloudflare provides this information in HTTP headers. You can see more information [in this article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs) but here is a configuration snippet relevant for your reverse proxy:

```
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;

#use any of the following two

real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
#real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

The list of Cloudflare IP ranges [is maintained here](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/ips/).

For the 2nd scenario (grey cloud), it sounds like there is a connectivity issue between `X.X.X.X` and your NGINX. You will want to diagnose that using tools such as `mtr` or also reviewing if you have any Firewall settings in Digitalocean that might prevent the traffic from passing through to your Droplet.

If you would consider a completely different approach for connecting to your application privately, I recommend [the following tutorial](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/warp-to-tunnel) as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for providing several solutions. I will try them and keep you updated.

Comment: You are welcome!